# Triggering DialogFlow with Face detection

Tags: dialogflow-es, face-detection, google-assistant-sdk

Does anyone know if there is a way to trigger DialogFlow from Face Detection API?
The DialogFlow conversation process is not very user friendly since you need to say :
"Ok Google, Talk to my app"

I've seen something about implicit invocations and deep links here:
https://blog.mirabeau.nl/nl/articles/creating_friendly_conversational_flows_using_google_deep_links/61fNoQEwS7WdUqRTMdo6J2
that provides a better approach

I'm trying to do something like this
https://www.forbes.com/sites/katiebaron/2018/06/07/ambient-tech-that-actually-works-hm-launches-a-voice-activated-mirror/#49b619634463
But with Google Assistant / Dialogflow / Vision API (Face detection)

Anyone has ideas how to do this in Google?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that using face detection to trigger Google Assistant is not possible. Google requires you to use a trigger word such as "Ok, Google Talk to my app" when you build actions. This is done due to privacy for the user and makes sure that the app cannot be triggered without the user talking to the device.

Implicit invocations and deep links are shortcuts in your conversations, but they can only be used if you trigger the assistant first by saying "Okay Google..." Thanks for reading my blog by the way :)

Comment: As an addendum, you could use the Dialogflow API to do direct communication between your client (mirror or whatever) using a Face Detection API as well. You just aren't able to integrate with the Google Assistan.t.